# Is a function still analytic if its infinite sequence of subsequent derivatives, at every point of its domain, grow faster than the factorial?

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion, analyticity

Taylor series have the nth derivative ($f^{(n)}(a)$) in their numerator and n! in their denominator. I was wondering what if the derivatives (for any point $a$) grows faster than the factorial. Does the function still equal it's Taylor series? Also, give examples of such functions.

Comment: 'Faster than the factorial' is not a precise enough statement. E.g. the $n$th derivative is $2^n n!$: in that case, the Taylor series still exists (and the radius of convergence is $1/2$).

Comment: But $\sum_n 2^n x^n$ doesn't converge for any $x$

Comment: I think it does when $|x|<1/2$

Comment: @RichardMartin I got it. I thought the condition 'derivatives grows faster than factorial' should have been enough for the radius of convergence to be zero everywhere.

Comment: Well colloquially you are right. If they are like $(2n)!$ or $n^n$ for example, then yes. But you need to be clearer about how much faster, that's all.

Comment: @RichardMartin So, is the function with derivatives $(2n)!$ considered analytic? Does that function even exist when the Taylor series doesn't converge anywhere?

Comment: No, as the power series doesn't converge anywhere except at 0.